# Django Boolean Field returns False in template while it actually is True

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, boolean

This is my models.py:

```
class Sherlock(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    wifi = models.BooleanField('Wifi', default=False)
```

And this is my views.py that contains more than just one context:

```
class OwnerDetails(generic.DetailView):
    template_name ='owners/venuedetails.html'
    model = Owner

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OwnerDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        self.pk = Owner.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        featurete_list = FeatureteImage.objects.filter(owner=self.pk)
        context['featurete_list'] = featurete_list

        sherlock = Sherlock.objects.filter(owner=self.pk)
        context['sherlock'] = sherlock
        return context
```

And this is my template:

```
{% if sherlock.wifi %}
    <p>Wifi</p>
{% else %}
    <p><s>Wifi</s></p>
{% endif %}
```

And when i go to /admin i have wifi checked. But i always get a crossed wifi ( the `<s>` tag in the template creates the crossed wifi )

My problem is that even though in my admin I have the wifi field checked and saved it still returns false to the template.

Comment: What is `amenities`? Where is it coming from? And you should never compare explicitly with True, always do `{% if amentities %}`.

Comment: You have a typo in `scherlock`/`sherlock`

Comment: @DanielRoseman excuse me for that i changed the values to make it clearer for the readers. i changed it and it doesn't work buddy.

Comment: @Sayse that's not the case

Comment: Changing the values doesn't make it any clearer for readers. Why would a `Sherlock` have a wifi boolean field? Another problem is that the error is often hidden when the example is changed.

Comment: @Alasdair your answer was correct with filter and get. post the answer and thank you very much. and yes i noticed it's making it worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines in your view and template do not match.

```
sherlock = Sherlock.objects.filter(owner=self.pk)

{% if sherlock.wifi %}
```

You can't access the `wifi` attribute on the queryset, you access it on the instance.

If the queryset might contain multiple items, then you can loop through the instances in the template.

```
{% for s in sherlock %}
    {% if s.wifi %}
    Wifi
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the queryset should only ever return a single instance, then you can use `get()` instead of `filter()`.

```
sherlock = Sherlock.objects.get(owner=self.pk)
```

You can improve this to handle the case where the object does not exist

```
try:
    sherlock = Sherlock.objects.get(owner=self.pk)
except Sherlock.DoesNotExist:
    # do something here
```

Sometimes the `get_object_or_404` shortcut is useful for this.

```
sherlock = get_object_or_404(Sherlock, owner=self.pk)
```

Finally, note that there is no need to compare to True in the template, just use

```
{% if sherlock.wifi %}
```

Comment: Yes yes thank you! sherlock = Sherlock.objects.get(owner=self.pk) that was my problem. and thank you for the extra info.